# Trigger to Limit number of Line Item per Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger that will prevent the number of Opp line item per Opportunity.

Upon checking the debug the size is returning 0, it should return the total number of line item in the Opportunity instead. Here's the code:

```
trigger LimitProduct on OpportunityLineItem (before insert) {

    list<String> lineOppId = new list<String>();
    list<OpportunityLineItem> lineItemList = [SELECT id, name
                                              FROM OpportunityLineItem
                                              WHERE OpportunityId IN: lineOppId];
    list<String> lineNewItemList = new list<String>();

    for(OpportunityLineItem olt : lineItemList){
        if(olt.OpportunityId != null){
            lineNewItemList.add(olt.OpportunityId);
        }  
    }
    for(OpportunityLineItem opp : trigger.new){
        //if(lineNewItemList.size() > 3){
         //   opp.addError('Errorr!');
            System.Debug('##### ' + lineNewItemList.size());
        //}   
    }
}
```

Any ideas why? What's the possible cause and fix? How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Please do not delete then recreate nearly identical posts. It puts you at risk that the system will flag your account and you will lose the ability to create new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a **before** trigger, the changes to the database have **not** been committed yet, so you can't query for the data. Accordingly, you wouldn't see the new rows being created yet. Change the trigger to an `after insert` trigger to see the correct values. Note that your trigger isn't bulkified. Nor, is it even necessary. Just create a normal Roll-Up Summary Field for the line items, and write a validation rule that stops more than 5 rows being added:

```
Product_Line_Count__c > 5
```

As code, you can write something like this:

```
trigger blockExtras on OpportunityLineItem (after insert) {
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(OpportunityLineItem record: Trigger.new) {
        oppIds.add(record.OpportunityId);
    }
    Set<Id> extras = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
        SELECT OpportunityId Id
        FROM OpportunityLineItem
        WHERE OpportunityId IN :oppIds
        GROUP BY OpportunityId
        HAVING COUNT(Id) > 5
    ]).keySet();
    for(OpportunityLineItem record: Trigger.new) {
        if(extras.contains(record.OpportunityId)) {
            record.addError('You cannot have more than five lines on an opportunity.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Except validation is supposed to happen in the before context. I would think it far more appropriate to meld the context records with the count of what already exists, rather than performing the validation in an after context.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Validation can occur before or after triggers--many people prefer validating in after triggers, because before triggers can alter the contents of fields, thus potentially invalidating data. For example, see Andrew Fawcett's [blog post](https://andyinthecloud.com/2015/04/19/considerations-placing-validation-code-in-an-apex-triggers/) on the matter. Of course, each developer is free to choose whichever they think is most appropriate, just be aware that each has drawbacks.

Comment: In an ideal world, that just means you should run validation last (after all field updates). Seems to me validating in the after context should at least be used as a last resort, though I guess it's not immediately clear what the cost is other than a longer running transaction than you need.

Comment: @AdrianLarson At least a few of my earlier answers on here say that pre-commit validation is preferred, but the "fields might change" argument at least softened my stance on the issue since then. Sure, pre-commit validation might be "faster", but it also might not be correct in all cases. Saying it's a "last resort" is a bit harsh; I would say that writing extra (longer, superfluous) code should be a last resort. That said, neither viewpoint is exactly wrong, and developer discretion is advisable either way.

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you so much master! I'm practicing how to code that's why. Your approach is way more better than mine. I also thought that using `after insert` will fire after the record has been inserted so that confuses me. Also I would like if the `GROUP BY` is still needed even if you used `SET`? Does set mean it prevents duplicate Id not Opportunity Id? Thanks again!

Comment: @NaofumiKun (a) `after insert` simply means the initial commit has happened, but the data is not fully committed and can still be rolled back (read [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)). (b) We need `GROUP BY` to get the count of line items per opportunity. Otherwise, this won't work correctly in bulk insert operations. The `HAVING` operator makes sure there's more than 5 Id values per grouping (OpportunityId). Basically, we have the database count the rows for us.

Comment: @sfdcfox last thing what's the `.keySet()` for after the query? Appreciate!

Comment: @NaofumiKun We're creating a Map from the query, then getting the "keys" from that map. This happens to be the Opportunity records that exceed five line items. These values are a Set, which can easily determine if a value is within it by using the `contains()` method.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you maintain a map of `OpportunityId` to count of child records. Start with the aggregates, then increment by your context records. Please note from **[Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)**:

> - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.

Given that you are validating record values, a move to the after context would be the incorrect coding pattern to apply here.

```
// initialize each key with zero
Map<Id, Integer> lineItemCounts = new Map<Id, Integer>();
for (OpportunityLineItem record : trigger.new)
{
    lineItemCounts.put(record.OpportunityId, 0);
}

// increment counts by what is in the database
for (AggregateResult result : [
    SELECT OpportunityId, count(Id) lineItemCount
    FROM OpportunityLineItem
    WHERE OpportunityId IN :lineItemCounts.keySet()
    GROUP BY OpportunityId
]){
    lineItemCounts.put(
        (Id)result.get('OpportunityId'),
        (Integer)result.get('lineItemCount')
    );
}

// increment counts by what is in the trigger context
// you can validate as you increment to avoid an additional loop
for (OpportunityLineItem record : trigger.new)
{
    Id key = record.OpportunityId;
    Integer lineItemCount = 1 + lineItemCounts.get(key);
    if (lineItemCount > 1) record.addError('some message');

    lineItemCounts.put(key, lineItemCount);
}
```

Comment: appreciate your help! Thank you, unfortunately I can only choose 1 best answer

Comment: FYI, that quote from the docs is... misleading. For the longest time (years, if I recall), I literally thought that addError would not work in an after trigger at all. I think it's statements like that which cause more confusion than anything. The docs often oversimplify an issue I guess for legibility, but what the docs don't say could fill a book or three. 